# Class 'Item' has no 'Objects' memberpylint(no-member)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import the model into my views but somehow it's giving me an error "Class 'Item' has no 'Objects' memberpylint(no-member)". I don't understand why?

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item

# def products(request):
#     context = {
#         'items': Item.objects.all()
#     }
#     return render(request, "products.html", context)

def item_list(request):
    context = {
        'items': Item.Objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "home-page.html", context)

def checkout(request):
    return render(request, "checkout.html")
```

here's my model for that

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('S', 'Shirt'),
    ('SW', 'Sportswear'),
    ('OW', 'Outwear')
)

LABEL_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'primary'),
    ('S', 'secondary'),
    ('D', 'danger')
)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    def _str_(self):
        return self.title


class Order(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title
```

Can anyone tell me what's it I'm doing wrong?

Same with the product function when I try to call the Item it's giving me the same error. That's why I commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Django specific [Pylint plugin](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django), I think this would resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Try removing the Pylint plugin and then run the code.Because there is not issue with the code.Might be some issue with your Pylint configuration.